# Infinite planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph such that $G=\underset{i\in I}{\cup}G_i$, $G_i=K_j, j=1,2,3,4$ ($K_j$ denotes the complete graph) and $|I| \leq c$, where $c$ is the cardinality of the real number. Is the graph $G$ planar? If so, is it necessary that $|I|\leq c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a planar embedding is especially an injective map $V\to\mathbb R^2$, the condition $|I|\le c$ is clearly necessary.

The remaining arguments may depend on how *planar embedding* is defined exactly in the presence of infinite graphs. If it is *only* (i.e. without any "separatio" assumptions) an injective map $f\colon V\to \mathbb R$ together with continuous maps $f_{ab}\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ for all edges $ab$ with $f_{ab}(0)=a$, $f_{ab}(1)=b$ and $f_{ab}(x)=f_{cd}(y)$ only if $x,y\in\{0,1\}$ or $ab=cd$ and $x=y$, then there is no need to keep distinct vertices or edges apart from each other: 
There is no problem in placing $c$ many copies of $K_1$ on a line segment, or $c$ many copies of $K_2$ on a square (in form of vertical lines, say).
Also, $c$ many copies of $K_3$ can be realized as nested triangles.

But with more than countably many copies of $K_4$ we get into trouble: Each embedding of a $K_4$ contains at leat one rational point in the interior of each of its three bounded faces. Since there are only countably many triples of rational points, there must be two distinct embeddings of $K_4$ for which we picked the same triple. This is not possible (why?)

Comment: A stronger known fact is that the plane does not contain uncountably many pairwise disjoint copies of the bipartitite graph $K_{1,3}$ (i.e., the letter Y).

Comment: Two single-character typos: "separatio" and "leat".  I think this means a connected planar graph can have at most countably many vertices? Or maybe you can fold a single chain of $c$ vertices into a square....